# Confused about problem where a function is an integral of another function in terms of a different variable.

Tags: calculus, integration

I found two possible solutions to a problem.  The first feels like the solution they wanted me to use, and the second feels like a snarky shortcut.

**The Problem**

I am presented with this problem (in Khan Academy, integral calculus):

> Given that  $g(x) = \int_{-8}^x (-2t+4)\ dt$,
> What is $g'(-3)$

**Solution 1**

At first this confused me, because the integrand is in terms of $t$ but the function is in terms of $x$.  I charged ahead though, and found that...

$\int (-2t+4)\ dt$

$=\int-2t\ dt + \int 4\ dt$

$=4t -t^2$

Evaluating the definite integral, I got...

$=(4x-x^2)-(4(-8)-(-8)^2) = 4x-x^2+96$

This answer is the required integral, which is referred to as $g'(x)$, I think, and so

$g(-3) = 4-2(-3) = 10$

**Solution 2**

The problem checked out and was marked as correct.  But then later on I looked at it again and felt like I had missed something.  If I know $g(x)$ is the integral and I'm looking for the derivative of that, is there any point to solving the integral?  Couldn't I just cheat and say...

If $g(x) = \int_{-8}^x (-2t+4)\ dt$ and $g'(-3)$ is its derivative when $x=-3$, then the function $g'(x)$ must be simply $(-2(-3)-4)$, which gives the same answer.  I'm all mixed up with my $x$ and $t$ terms, and I would like to know if this second solution is just a happy accident or a reasonable way to solve this problem.

Comment: It is definitely no accident, it is a direct consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which says that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=f(x)$.

Comment: If this is high school Calculus, which emphasizes problem solving over *proofs*, then the problem composer probably intended your first method.  Alternatively, if this is (for example) a college course in Real Analysis, with heavy emphasis given to theorems/proofs, then the problem composer probably intended your second method.

Comment: @user2661923 it is neither, just an adult who never got to learn this in school

Answer (score 1):

The "t" in $\int_{-8}^x (-2t+ 4)dt$ is a "dummy variable"- it plays no role in the answer.
$\int_{-8}^x (-2s+ 4)ds$

$\int_{-8}^x (-2y+ 4)dy$

$\int_{-8}^x (-2z+ 4)dz$

$\int_{-8}^x (-2\nu+ 4)d\nu$

all give exactly the same result,
$4x- x^2+ 96$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (or at least one version of it) states as follows:

- If $F(x)$ is a function defined on the interval $[a, b]$ and it satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(b) - F(a)$.

So if we replace one of the bounds of integration with the variable $x$, we get:

$$\int_a^x f(t) dt = F(x) - F(a)$$

and we can differentiate this with respect to $x$, giving us

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) dt & = & \frac{d}{dx} (F(x) - F(a)) \\
& = & F'(x) \\
& = & f(x)\end{eqnarray}$$

noting that since $F(a)$ is a constant, its derivative with respect to $x$ is zero.

There is nothing wrong with your first approach, but the second approach is much more useful in cases where you can't directly integrate $f$, or where the bounds of integration become more complicated.