# Why do I need to know the bounds of integration if I'm taking the derivative of a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am asked to...

> Given that $F(x)=\int_1^{2x}\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}\ dt$, 
> Find $F'(x)$.

I am utterly confused at how to even begin.  $F'(x)$ will be the derivative of $F(x)$, of course.  But $F(x)$ is itself an integral.  So doesn't it follow that $F(x)=\frac{d}{dt}[\int\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}dt]$?  And isn't the derivative of an integral just the original function?  Does $F(x)=\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}$ Furthermore, why do I need to know that the bounds of integration are $1$ and $2x$, if I'm only taking the derivative the integral?

There seems to be some fundamental understanding about problems like this one, and [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765887/confused-about-problem-where-a-function-is-an-integral-of-another-function-in-te) that I am lacking, and I would appreciate a nod in the right direction!

Comment: You have to use the chain rule in this case. Since $(\int_a^x f(t)dt)'=f(x)$ then $(\int_a^{b(x)} f(t)ft)'=f(b(x)).b'(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot conflate definite integrals with indefinite integrals - they are two different (albeit related) concepts.

An indefinite integral is defined (up to a constant) as an antiderivative of the integrand, so if you had one of those you could indeed write $$\frac{d}{dt}\int\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}\text{.}$$

But you were not given an indefinite integral, you were given a definite integral, which means you must relate integration and differentiation via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  This has two parts, one if which says that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=f(x)\text{,}\tag{1}$$
provided that $a$ is constant.

But there is a subtlety here which is that (1) requires the lower limit to be constant and the upper limit to be exactly your variable of differentiation.  If instead you have some function of $x$ in your upper limit, then you have to use the chain rule, which gives
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)}f(t)\,dt=f(g(x))g'(x)\text{.}\tag{2}$$
In your case (2) becomes
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{2x}\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{(2x)^2}{(2x)^2+1}\cdot 2=\frac{8x^2}{4x^2+1}\text{.}$$